# collision isn't recognized using touchstart event

Tags: javascript, touch, html5-canvas

I am working on creating a touch enabled game using examples from the book "Foundation HTML5 Animation with JavaScript. One of the examples from the book shows basic touch functionality that works but not completely. Here is a link to the example http://jsfiddle.net/yrXCN/3/

According to the function below if you touch the canvas within the ball it should log the message "in ball: touchstart" however I have yet to make it work. It will recognize the ball when you move into it, but for some reason it wont recognize a first touch.

If I change the code to use mouse listeners it works as intended.

```
canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (utils.containsPoint(ball.getBounds(), touch.x, touch.y)) {
      log.value = "in ball: touchstart";
    } else {
      log.value = "canvas: touchstart";
    }
  }, false);
```

Comment: Are you trying to run this in your desktop browser? Touch events fire on touch-screen devices (like mobile phones).

Comment: I am testing on my mobile phone. Sorry, I should've mentioned that it needs to be tested on a mobile device or emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 element.addEventListener('touchstart', function (event) {
    touch.isPressed = true;
    touch.event = event;
}, false);
```

If "touchstart" is fired on your ball `touch.x` and `touch.y` are undefined and so you do not recognize the touch on the ball. You track `touch.x` and `touch.y` in your touchmove event and that is why you recognize the touch is on the ball while moving.

Edit: You can solve this by setting `touch.x` and `touch.y` inside the touchstart event at line 88-91